# Multiple connections in Swift - how to figure out which button was pressed?

Tags: swift

I have four buttons all with the same connection to a single function within the code, and I can't figure out how to determine *which* button sent the request. ~_~

Comment: How can we know why you cannot figure out?Add something that you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set each `UIButton`'s `tag` to "1" "2" "3" "4"

```
func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if sender.tag == 1 {
        //Code for button1
    } else if sender.tag == 2 {
        //Code for button2
    } else if sender.tag == 3 {
        //Code for button3
    } else if sender.tag == 4 {
        //Code for button1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check the title of the button pressed for instance with
button.currentTitle

If all buttons have the same one, you can check its restoration id

Answer (score 1):

As a 3rd alternative (now) you can use the tag property and simply number the single buttons.

```
func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) -> () {
    if let button = sender as? UIButton {
        switch (button.tag){
        case 1:
        //code
        case 2:
        //code
        case 3:
        //code
        case 4:
        //code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) -> () {
    if let button = sender as? UIButton {
        println("\(button.currentTitle)")
    } else {
        println("sender is not a UIButton!")
    }
}
```

Comment: also pointed out in another [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046540/get-button-pressed-id-on-swift-via-sender/30046626#30046626) tags are a good option if the titles are different