# Passing value to insert in an IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want to pass an `Int` to a function so I can change the background color of the right `UIButton`

Example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!


changeBackground(1);

func changeBackground(number:Int){

button(number).backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()


}
```

Comment: Search your question before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a tag for each Button in interface Builder, or create an Array containing your Buttons. Then you pass the index of the button you want to update to your function.

Edit:

Instead of passing in a number it probably would be better to pass in the button itself.
This way you can re-use the method more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done it differently. Create a global variable e.g.:

```
var buttonColor: Int = 0
```

and do a switch statement or if-else so that when:

```
switch(buttonColor):
case 1:
 //set color here
case 2:
 //set color here
```

also this can help further to know which button to be changed since UI components have storyboard ID:

[Get button pressed id on Swift via sender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046540/get-button-pressed-id-on-swift-via-sender)