# How to identify a specific button as a sender

Tags: ios, swift, button, sender

I'm passing data between view controllers, and am trying to send a specific int from one view controller to the other.

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let werrk = segue.destination as! ViewControllerTwo
    werrk.dataSent = (sender as! UIButton).title(for: .normal)!
    }
```

It sends the title of a button to a new view controller successfully. To also identify a specific button and send a int, I'm imagining adding some if/else statements like...

```
if sender = button1 {
work.dataSent = 7
}
```

I can't find the correct commands to make this happen however. 
I'm new to all of this and any help would be appreciated. Thanks very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get button pressed id on Swift via sender](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046540/get-button-pressed-id-on-swift-via-sender)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to add an IBOutlet for each of the buttons you want to compare in your code and then link the outlet to the actual button in your storyboard. Then you can check if the sender is that particular button.

If this does not make sense, please let me know and I'll elaborate further.

Comment: Thanks.  I do have that, (@IBOutlet weak var buttonTwo: UIButton!
) and it's linked to the storyboard, but I don't know the specific language of how to identify the button in my if/then command.

Comment: OK, can you provide the code for the whole method where you have to use the if/then command? If `sender` is a type other than `UIButton` you'd have to cast it to `UIButton` as in your first bit of code - but I figured you knew that part since you provided the code :) So I'm not quite seeing what the issue is since you have all the bits necessary but I might be missing something ...

Comment: Everything I'm doing seems logically correct, but I'm new to this and just assume I'm making an obvious error in how I'm specifying the sender. I get an error: "Cannot convert value of type 'UIButton!' to expected argument type.

Comment: I think the issue is that you are trying to assign (=) vs. compare(==). If you modify your code as follows, it should work:
`if (sender as! UIButton) == button1 {`

Comment: That did it. Thanks very much!

Comment: Happy to help :) Could you please mark the answer as "correct"?

Answer (score 2):

try adding a Tag on each button then use it to identify on if/switch

```
Button1.tag = 1
```

and on your event trigger do something like

```
if (sender.tag == 1) {
   // do stuffs
}
```

Comment: I didn't think of/am not familiar with the .tag deal. Will try it, thanks!

Comment: I up voted because I'd think this too. Too bad the OP didn't understand the difference between "=" and "==" - and the question wasn't edited.

Comment: Thanks. Anyhow, @tfcamp you might want to mark an answer as accepted if it helped you with you question.