# UIButton With Unique Identifier

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton

Searched questions here 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046540/get-button-pressed-id-on-swift-via-sender)
but not completely solving my problem.

Problem here is I have around 100 buttons in UIScrollView, and based on response from server I have to highlight buttons (i.e. Server sends me "Button_Unique_Id": "Button_ABC_1"). Now here the problem is how do I create a UIButton with unique identifier "Button_ABC_1", in such a way that when I get response from server, I can identify my button with the Button_Unique_Id value and do alterations just to that button.

```
button.tag = index
```

This approach fails as I can't identify button with value I got "Button_ABC_1"

I would appreciate response best practiced.

Comment: Could you Please show your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep references to your buttons in a `Dictionary` (`[String : UIButton]`) and use those strings as keys, then you can get the appropriate button by simply asking for it:

```
let buttonOfInterest = buttons["Button_ABC_1"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create subclass of `UIButton` and add `id` instance variable whatever type you want. Good Luck!

**EDIT**

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    var id : String?
}
```

Usage:

```
let btn = MyButton(type: .custom)
btn.id = "MY_BUTTON_ID"
```

Something like that.

Comment: can you give an example or some link?, do i have to create Sub Class for each UIButton?

Comment: You don't have to create subclass for each button. After creation, just assign your unique id to the button, and keep a reference in an array or dictionary for later identification of the button.

Comment: Ok I am trying this solution. Will get back in a while.

Comment: I think this solution will eventually end Up adding to Dictionary like ([String : UIButton])

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Button.tag = integerValue` for storing integer value with button.
You can manage an array of those data and bind that array with button tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum ButtonIdentifier: String {
//you could name the enum as ButtonMapper
//let the case be same as server response string
case button_abc_0
case button_abc_1
case button_abc_2

var id: int {
//fetch the id from the server response string & return - here fetch the integer from the rawValue.
//Or else you have to use the switch for returning the id which is not feasible when you have 100s of data - better to extract from the response string
}

guard let buttonIdentifier = ButtonIdentifier (rawValue: serverResponceString) else { return }
```

Using forEach loop you can tag (integer value) the buttons at once

```
updateButton(with tag: buttonIdentifier.id)
```